# Drupal 7 js compression generating 6 files

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using drupal_add_js and drupal_add_library to add some js to my site. But when I turn on the drupal js compression, drupal is aggregating the files but it's generating 6 files and Yslow is saying that it's too much files. Is there any way to force drupal to aggregate more the files? It'd be great if drupal 7 generates only 2 or 3 files per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, the larger number of files can actually *save* bandwidth on subsequent requests, something that YSlow doesn't take into account.  Aggregating everything into a single giant file is really only optimal for visitors that load a single page and no others.

I wrote an article explaining the details in [Drupal 7: Taking control of CSS and JS aggregation](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-taking-control-css-and-js-aggregation).

To reduce the number of files, you can try the [Core Library](http://drupal.org/project/core_library) module. The article above also has some example code that will group the files together using `hook_css_alter()` and `hook_js_alter()`.